# React & Redux propagation changes in state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

A simple question: I have two components, with two reducers. The State of the application, basically divided in two, would be something like `{stateComponent1: object, stateComponent2: object ....}.` `Component2`, in addition, "uses" the state of the first component, this is done by the `MapStateToProps` function in which we assign the `stateComponent1` and the `stateComponent2` (the "own").

The question is, when `Component1` performs a dispatch that causes `stateComponent1` to change, `Component2` should be re-rendered, since it has in its props the `stateComponent1`? The point is that this does not happen.

EDIT: I show you my code

I have a store that does the login, basically this is:

ACTIONS

```
export const actionCreators = {
    requestLogin: (credentials: Credentials): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_REQUEST',
            isFetching: true,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            credentials: credentials
        });
        const config = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            body: `username=${credentials.username}&password=${credentials.password}`
        };
        const loginTask = fetch(`http://localhost:50679/api/jwt`, config).then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
            if (!data.idToken) {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE',
                    isFetching: false,
                    isAuthenticated: false,
                    message: 'Error en el login'
                });
                return Promise.reject(data);
            } else {
                // If login was successful, set the token in local storage
                if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
                    localStorage.setItem('idToken', data.idToken);
                }
                // Dispatch the success action
                dispatch({
                    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
                    isFetching: false,
                    isAuthenticated: true,
                    idToken: data.idToken
                });
            }
        });
    },
```

REDUCERS:

```
export const reducer: Reducer<LoginState> = (state: LoginState, action: KnownAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
        return {
            isFetching: true,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            idToken: '',
            credentials: action.credentials,
            message: ''
        };
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
        return {
            isFetching: false,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            idToken: action.idToken,
            credentials: null,
            message: ''
        };
    case 'LOGIN_FAILURE':
        return {
            isFetching: false,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            idToken: '',
            credentials: null,
            message: action.message
        };
    case 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS':
        return {
            isFetching: true,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            idToken: '',
            credentials: null,
            message: ''
        };
    default:
        // The following line guarantees that every action in the KnownAction union has been covered by a case above
        const exhaustiveCheck: any = action;
    }

    return state || unloadedState;
};
```

Now, I have a component that subscribes to the login state, which must "find out" when this state changes, ie, for example when login is done, I do this:

```
return connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) =>
    Object.assign(state.login, state.location, state.history)
)(AuthenticatedComponent);
```

The problem is that my AuthenticationComponent component does not know when the state.login has changed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - if Component 2 uses `stateComponent1`, then it makes sense that Component 2 should re-render when that segment of the state changes?

Comment: Well, let's say the state segment of component1 is part of the props of component 2, so I understand that when it changes (via a Component 1 dispatch), Component 2 should be re-rendered, right? At least that's that I thought

Comment: Could you share your reducer's code?

Answer (score 0):

You should override shouldComponentUpdate.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.stateComponent1 !== this.props.stateComponent1) {
    return false;  
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This option seems logical, but should not do it automatically? I would like to understand why when the prop of a component changes, the component is rendered again, but it doesn't work the same when this prop is the segment of the state that has been assigned to it by means of the connect () function of redux

Comment: Maybe, the reducer is not mutating state correctly. Usually reducer should return `{ ...state, segment: { ...state.segment, mod: 'xyz' } }` instead of doing `state.segment.mod = 'xyz'`. This is especially true when nested objects are involved.